# I want to display data using a click of a button, but i have more than 2 buttons on 1 form.

Tags: php

I have two buttons (save and display), so when i click display it must display data in textboxes the save it should save data into database

```
<?php echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" 
    action="index.php?action=Add Post" class="standard">';        
       if (!isset( $_POST['calculate'])) {$TheStringpg =" SELECT sum(income_amount)from income where (income_date Between '". $_POST['start_date']."'   and '". $_POST['end_date'] ."') and traditionalcouncil_name='".$Trad."' AND financialyear_id = '". $Finyear ."'  "; $TheResultpg = pg_query($SYSconnMADE, $TheStringpg); while($arrpg = pg_fetch_array($TheResultpg)){ $income_balance = $arr['0'] ;
    }
    $TheString4 = " SELECT sum(expenditure_amount)from expenditure where (expenditure_date Between '". $_POST['start_date']."'
      and '". $_POST['end_date'] ."') and  traditionalcouncil_name='".$Trad."' AND financialyear_id = '". $Finyear ."'  ";$TheResultp = pg_query($SYSconnMADE, $TheString4);           
         while($arr1 = pg_fetch_array($TheResultp)) { 
    $expenditure_balance = $arr['0'] ;
    }  }   
    echo '</select>
    <input type="submit" name="calculate" alt="display" value="display">'; ` 


  ?>
```

Comment: so what is the issue here?

Comment: Actually i have 3 forms, the form i select section and it calls another form with people who fall under that section so i select person then select start date and end date then i click display to display data into textboxes it execute to the save button

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit"  alt="display" value="display" name="display">';`

```
  '<input type="submit"  alt="display" value="save" name="save">'; ` 

 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['save']));

  {
// from data
   // insert query
 }

    if(isset($_POST['display']));
   {
   // post form data and disply

  }

   ?>
```

Comment: it not working, it execute the save one or should i paste the whole html and php code?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="display" value="Display" />
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    // Your query
} else if (isset($_POST['display'])){   
    // Your query
}
```

Comment: It is not working.Actually i have 3 forms, the form i select section and it calls another form with people who fall under that section so i select person then select start date and end date then i click display to display data into textboxes it execute to the save button

Comment: when i click the save button i want to redirect it to another page